# Loop over two columns to check for identity of elemnts and create new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following dataset: (this is just a little part)

[image: Screenshot]

- Right now each "product*id" corresponds to an "order*_id"
- I have to create e new column with the "product_id" for each "order_id_OK"
- the majority of elements of "order_id_OK" are also in "order_id" but in a different order

So the objective would be to have a column where each "product_id" corresponds to the row of "order_id_OK" and not of "order_id"

Right now i'm trying to set up a for loop:

```
l = []
for i in df["order_id_OK"]:
    for j in df["order_id"]:
        if i == j:
            for x in df["product_id"]:
                l.append(x)
```

any idea?

Comment: Will you please provide a text sample of your dataset? I can't copy/paste from an image.

Answer (score 0):

you can merge your dataframe with itself, the output will be a dataframe where 
`data['order_id'][j]==data['order_id_OK'][i]` (i and j same meaning as used in your for loops).

```
merged_data=data.merge(data, left_on=['order_id'], right_on=['order_id_OK'], how='inner')
```

in the merged data you will find new columns `'order_id_OK_y'` and `'product_id_x'` corresponding to your desired output.